# TEAMS - graph API: Tab reference is missing from the message

Tags: graph, microsoft-teams

When I add a new tab there is a message about it with a link to that tab. If I request that message through the GRAPH API, there is only a body
"Added a new tab at the top of this channel. Here's a link."
but not the link. Earlier it was there as an attachment, but now the attachment list is empty. Is there any different approach to get that link?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [get tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamstab-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) graph api to get the "webUrl".

Comment: unfortunately this is not enough. I need a relationship between the post and the tab.